# Sorting outlook favorites

Tags: vba, sorting, outlook, favorites

I have 5 accounts in outlook and have 20 favorite folders taken from those that I would like to appear in the same order each time I open outlook. The order they appear each time is pretty random. Is there a way to run a script on opening that will sort the folders into same order each time I open

I have looked through the Office VBA reference and cant find anything there that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the folders in the Outlook UI by explicitly setting the `PR_SORT_POSITION` property on each subfolder, for example, the following code shows the sort position of each folder in Outlook:

```
For Each folder In objMainFolder.Folders
        folder_index_property = folder.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x30200102")
        folder_index = folder.PropertyAccessor.BinaryToString(folder_index_property)
        MsgBox folder.Name & ", " & CInt("&h0" & folder_index(0)) 
Next
```

To set up the sort order you need to use the [PropertyAccessor.SetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor.setproperty) method which sets the property specified by `SchemaName` to the value specified by `Value`. If the property does not exist and the `SchemaName` contains a valid property specifier, then `SetProperty` creates the property and assigns the value specified by `Value`. If the property does exist and `SchemaName` is valid, then `SetProperty` assigns the property with the value specified by `Value`.

```
Sub DemoPropertyAccessorSetProperty() 
 Dim myProp As String 
 Dim myValue As Integer
 Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor 
 'Get first item in the inbox 
 Set oMail = _ 
 Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items(1) 
 
 myProp = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x30200102" 
 myValue = 1 
 'Set value with SetProperty call 
 'If the property does not exist, then SetProperty 
 'adds the property to the object when saved. 
 'The type of the property is the type of the element 
 'passed in myValue. 
 On Error GoTo ErrTrap 
 Set oPA = oMail.PropertyAccessor 
 oPA.SetProperty myProp, myValue 
 
 'Save the item 
 oMail.Save 
 Exit Sub 
ErrTrap: 
 Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description 
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for replying but did you paste all the code you intended please

Comment: I've just listed a sample code in the post.

Comment: Have you tested this on a recent Outlook installation?  It definitely used to work, but I am seeing that my Outlook (Version 2202 on the Semi-Annual Enterprise Channel) seems to no longer honor this property for sorting.